# Writing to text file on in GWT project?

Tags: file, google-app-engine, gwt, fwrite, java-io

In my GWT project(it is a game) i want to store the score of users who playing it, into a file located on server side. And to display them in the output using String.

I can read data from file, but I can't write into file, it always says Google App Engine not supports this.
I would like to know why Google App Engine don't support it?
Is there any way I can add data to a file on server side?
please be free to add all your opinions, every thing will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write into a `file` on App Engine, but you have two other options.

First, if your text is under 1MB, you can store your text in Datastore using [Text entity](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Properties_and_Value_Types).

Second, you can store your text in a [Blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview).

Comment: I am sure that my file will not exceed 1MB, it a 10 pair of (String name, int score). So which one you prefer will be useful for me?
And will you please provide some samples for this?

Comment: For your needs: neither of these options. You can save them as 10 separate entities, or one entity with a String property. You should read on how to store data on App Engine: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview

Comment: I will prefer One entity with String of array or List.

Comment: @ all: If I store a text file in Blobstore, can I write to that text file? or I can only read it?

Comment: You can retrieve this file, update it, and store again. If you don't change the blob key, it will rewrite the old version. There is also an option now to store files in Google Cloud Storage, which is cheaper than Blobstore.

Answer (score 0):

No codes or dependent jar files for text file writing can be used in GWT project, but codes for executing cmd commands can.

Use a trick like this to circumvent the problem. Donwload [commons-codec-1.10](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar) and add to build path. Add the following snippet which can be copied online to CMDUtils.java and put in the 'shared' package:

```
public static StringBuilder execute(String... commands) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = runtime.exec(new String[] { "cmd" });

        // put a BufferedReader
        InputStream inputstream = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(proc.getOutputStream());

        for (String command : commands) {
            stdin.println(command);
        }
        stdin.close();

        // MUST read the output even though we don't want to print it,
        // else waitFor() may fail.
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
            result.append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Add corresponding ABCService.java and ABCServiceAsync.java and then add:

```
public class ABCServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements ABCService {


public String sendText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    text= Base64.encodeBase64String(text.getBytes());

    final String command = "java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar \"D:\\abc.jar\" " + text;
    CMDUtils.execute(command);
    return "";      
}
```

And abc.jar is created as an executable jar in which the entry point contains a main method like this:

```
public static final String TEXT_PATH = "D:\\texts-from-user.txt";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String text = args[0];

    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(TEXT_PATH, true));
    text = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(text));
    writer.write("\n" + text);
    writer.close();
}
```

I have tried this and it works successfully for text file writing for a GWT project.